# Splitting in Brasero

Tags: brasero

I would like to split a track manually in Brasero, trimming out unwanted bits of audio. However, this function does not seem to be working ie only 2 seconds are showing on the bar, whilst the track is an hour and a half.

If i cant get Brasero to work is there another program available for this job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Best App for editing Audio on Ubuntu is [Audacity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/audacity/).

You can install it from terminal by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

**Remove unwanted audio from the recording** (From the [Official Documentation](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/splitting_a_recording_into_separate_tracks.html)) :

1- Set [Snap To](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/selection_toolbar.html#snap): Off in the [Selection Toolbar](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/selection_toolbar.html)

2- Click the Skip to Start button [image: img1]

3- Zoom in until you can see from the start of the track to the start of the music

4- Click and drag from the start of the music to the start of the track

5- Click on Edit > [Delete](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/edit_menu.html#delete)

Save your work! Click on File > [Save Project](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/file_menu.html#save).

Comment: Don't know where you got that PPA, it is in repos though so better to just `sudo apt-get install audacity`

Comment: Oneiric? The PPA doesn't contains a package for supported Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i fixed it !